# how can I pass parameter to a reportdocument and print it directly

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

how can I pass parameter to a reportdocument and print it directly
this is my code:

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
ParameterField p=new ParameterField();
p.Name="parm1";
ParameterDiscreteValue pv = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
pv.Value = "value1";
p.CurrentValues.Add(pv);
string str = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Print\\rpt1.rpt");
//rd.SetParameterValue("parm1", "test");
rd.Load(str);
rd.ParameterFields.Add(p);
var dialog = new PrintDialog();
rd.PrintOptions.PrinterName = dialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
rd.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

Comment: What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't now actually.but I change `rd.Load(str);` before adding parameters like this:

```
 ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
    rd.Load(str);
    ParameterField p=new ParameterField();
    p.Name="parm1";
    ParameterDiscreteValue pv = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    pv.Value = "value1";
    p.CurrentValues.Add(pv);
    string str = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Print\\rpt1.rpt");
    //rd.SetParameterValue("parm1", "test");

    rd.ParameterFields.Add(p);
    var dialog = new PrintDialog();
    rd.PrintOptions.PrinterName = dialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
    rd.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
it works correctly.
```